# How can I avoid God Class anti-pattern on this design

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I think I designed my app focusing all the logic in one single class (A). I have been reading that is not a good practise to do this. Class A have a lot of nested logic, each method of Solve() uses as input the result of the previous ones. I dont know if I should create separate classes for DoTask1, DoTask2, DoTask3 and DoTask4, and instantiate them from Solve(). Would that be better? I know I can also create separate classes with static methods but I have read that too many static methods are bad.

```
 Main()
 {
   A a = new A()
   a.Solve()
 }


 A()
 {
     Solve()
     {
        partialresult1 = DoTask1()
        partialresult2 = DoTask2(partialresult1)
        partialresult3 = DoTask3(partialresult2)
        finalresult = DoTask4(partialresult3)
     }

     DoTask1(){} 
     DoTask2(){} 
     DoTask3()
     {
        B b = new B()
        b.doWathever() 
     } 
     DoTask4(){} 
 }


 B()
 {
     doWhatever(){} 
 }
```

Comment: This might be better answered over at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Though I would also suggest that you provide a more specific example of what you are doing. Class structure is dependent upon what it represents and how it should interact with other classes. Without examples or an in-depth explanation it would be mostly guess-work to provide much direction.

Comment: it would be a better question on the codereview site. Also look at [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to know without the full extent of the problem but I'll take a guess and make a suggestion.

You have different payloads and based on them, you want to apply different tasks.

I would, at first create the ITask interface:

```
public interface ITask {
     Result DoWork(PartialResult res);
}
```

Now you can create task classes that can do some part of the work. The client could create the list and execute accordingly.

```
public Task1: ITask {
    public Result DoWork(PartialResult res) {
         // some work here
    }
}
```

Now as an extra, you could use the AbstractFactory design pattern. Each abstract factory implementation, will create the list of tasks needed for a specific job. The client can the use them to execute the payload.

Those two solutions will probably make your super class obsolete

For more information on the AbstractFactory design pattern,  check: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/abstract-factory

Comment: My tasks are all manipulation on a single list of words. Task1 removes all words except nouns, Task2 removes plural nouns, Task3 checks what pronouns are associated with the remaining nouns (for example if the noun is "people" it returns "he, she, they"  if the noun is London it returns "where"), and Task4 prints all. PartialresultX is just the same list but each time it contains less items.

Comment: No need for the abstract factory then as it would seem overkill. Just create the filter classes and have the client user them.